# What is the proper way of combining 2 documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I currently have 2 collections:

`users` that looks like:

```
const User = new Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    refreshTokens:{
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    // ID of the guild a user belongs to
    guildID:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'guilds',
        default: '61a679e18d84bff40c2f88fd',
        required: true
    },
    power:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 100
    }
})
```

`guilds` contains the objectID as _id and a field "name".

Now I would like to get a document by username and also the information of the guild that the user belongs to.

I read about using `db.collection.aggregate` this however results in all users and their guild information. Is it possible to use `$match` inside the aggregation to just get that single username? I'm fairly new to MongoDB and am just trying things out. If you have any resources or documentation I'd be happy to read those too!

In SQL it would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users where username = 'SomeUsername' INNER JOIN guilds on users.guildID = guilds.id
```

Comment: You can find a suitable operators from: [SQL to Aggregation Mapping chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregations can solve this (not recommended)

```js
userCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'guilds',
      as: 'guild',
      localeField: 'guildID',
      foreignField: '_id',
    }
  },
  {
    $unwrap: {
      path: '$guilds',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { 'guild._id': guildId },
        { ... other options ... }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

While this works and can be reasonably fast depending on your indexes and number of documents it can be better to add frequently queried fields to the related documents. In your case: add guildId and guildName to your user.

While this duplicates data and might not be considered best practice in relational dbs it is common to do this in document based databases. This is the fastest solution.

The alternative to an aggregation and embedding guildData into the user is to send two queries. One for the user, then one for the guild. This is called the relationship-pattern. This is the most common solution I believe)

Many (all?) ODM libraries, such as mongoose, handle the resolving of relationships automatically for you (mongoose calls this population). Which can simplify querying a lot, I think!

Comment: Would you recommend using duplicate data for smaller sized arrays and use aggregatings for larger ones? Let's say 25 object ids?

Comment: I recommend duplicating data for data that will (almost) always be fetched with the related document. For others I recommend using the relationship pattern